# Run JSX script on click of HTML button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

Sorry, this is my first ever question, and I'm probably just dumb and don't understand something easy.
I have a webpage made in HTML and React there is a text box and button. I am trying to call a JSX function on click of the button.  When you click the button, it is supposed to run some JSX code that will get something from the GitHub API and return it as HTML. That is why I am using JSX and not JavaScript. I found this code on another question and I modified it. I am new to JavaScript and JSX. When I put something in the textbox and click the button, the console logs: `myFunction is not defined`.
Is there any way to fix this?
I have a separate file called index.jsx that has all the code inside. Here it is:

```js
 /**
 * See https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#get-branch
 *
 * Example Github api request:
 * https://api.github.com/repos/ta-dachi/eatsleepcode.tech/branches/master
 */
class LatestCommitComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            author: "",
            branch: "",
            date: "",
            sha: "",
            link: ""
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Replace this with your own repo
        // https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/branches/master
        fetch(
            // This right below is what I am trying to replace from the text box
            "https://api.github.com/repos/datkat21/datkat21.github.io/branches/master"
        )
            .then(response => {
                response.json().then(json => {
                    console.log(json);
                    this.setState({
                        author: json.commit.author.login,
                        authorurl: json.commit.author.url,
                        avatar: json.commit.author.avatar_url,
                        branch: json.name,
                        date: json.commit.commit.author.date,
                        link: json._links.html,
                        authorpage: json.commit.author.html_url,
                        commit_url: json.commit.html_url,
                        commit_title: json.commit.commit.message,
                    });
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
            // This part shows the response from the GitHub API as HTML shown in the browser
                <div>{this.state.author}<br></br><a href={this.state.authorpage}><img src={this.state.avatar} alt="Loading..." class="img" /></a></div>

                <div><a href={this.state.link}>Branch: {this.state.branch}</a></div><br></br>

                <div>Message: {this.state.commit_title}</div>

                <div>Date: {this.state.date}</div>

                

                <div></div>

            </div>
        );
    }
;}

ReactDOM.render(<LatestCommitComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Sorry if the code is too long.
I don't know how to call that file on click of the button. If anyone could help, that would be good!
Thanks.

Edit: Here is the HTML code:

```html
<head>
    <title>Begin</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css" />
    <script type="text/jsx" src="../render.jsx"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="index.jsx"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            var GitUrl = document.getElementsByName("GitUrl")[0].value;
            render(); // The function returns the product of p1 and p2
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/jsx" render() { render; return ( <div>

        <div>{this.state.author}<br></br><a href={this.state.authorpage}><img src={this.state.avatar} alt="Loading..." class="img" /></a></div>
        
                    <div><a href={this.state.link}>Branch: {this.state.branch}</a></div><br></br>
        
                    <div>Message: {this.state.commit_title}</div>
        
                    <div>Date: {this.state.date}</div>
        
        
        
                    <div></div>
        
                </div>
            );
        }
        
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="begin-create-done.html" method="get">
        User/Repo URL:<br><br> <input type="text" name="GitUrl">
        <br>

    </form>
</body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Get data</button> <!--button that should run script-->

</html>
```

Sorry if I'm just dumb and dont understand something. I'm trying to call the script when you click on the button as defined in the HTML code

Comment: Is any other part of the webpage using react?

Comment: It is just one page and it has some scripts.

Comment: Does the page contain react anywhere?

Comment: I don't know what react is, I think it's JSX, I added my HTML code to see if that helps.

Comment: Does any of this code currently work? AFAIK, JSX won't automatically work in a browser. Consider reading https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while I don't see your button in your code, within your class you can create a function called `fetchGithub` (or something like that) then you add a property to your button that MIGHT look like this
`<button onClick={fetchGithub}>Fetch Github</button>`

Inside the `fetchGithub` function you can make a `fetch` call to the API and get your data. Then you can `setState` with the results and display it on your page.

edit: english

Comment: The OP hasn’t given a reason to believe the rest of the page even uses react...

Comment: the answer to the question is technically correct. I recommend the OP read up on creating react apps. https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Comment: How do I create a function in JSX? Is it `function myFunction(){ // code }`

Comment: It seems you're new to React (we've all been there). I'd start from reading on tutorials as I've linked above. Furthermore, function declarations in React Class Components are initialized the same way as the `componentDidMount()` function in your question.

Comment: @Kat21 please note that JSX _is not_ JavaScript, but a "[syntax extension](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)". It requires conversion to JavaScript (at the time of writing) before use in a browser.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I tried creating a function and again I get the same `fetchGithub is not defined` error. I have the script linked in the header: <script type="text/jsx" src="../render.jsx"></script>

Comment: as @evolutionxbox has stated, if you are not creating a React App, your code will not work. JSX must be compiled into javascript for it to work. Please read about creating React Apps.

Comment: I don't know what a react app is, I just have jsx and html

Comment: @Kat21 We know that. Which is why we're asking you to read up about react. Otherwise you'll be stuck and won't go anywhere with this.

Comment: I use Visual Studio Code and the Live Server extension if that helps

Comment: JSX is a syntax extension written BY Facebook (the creator of the React framework) to be used to build REACT applications. You can not use JSX in any other way than as part of a React Project. Please read about JSX, React, and how they are used before furthering this discussion.

Comment: The JSX code works even without the text box so I think I am using a react app because it has the script tags and the html like i just read from the website

Comment: Yeah the page is in react and I fixed it. Thanks